# Many to many. files is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django

I'm trying with relationship in django

**models**

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to="files"

class UserBuyFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
```

**views.py**

```
def buy_file(request,id):
    f = File.objects.get(id=id)
    user_buy_file = UserBuyFile.objects.create(files=f,user=request.user)
```

I have this error:

> 'files' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def buy_file(request,id):
    f = File.objects.get(id=id)
    user_buy_file, dummy_created = UserBuyFile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user_buy_file.files.add(f)
```

I also recommend you set `unique=True` for the field `user` in model `UserBuyFile`:

```
class UserBuyFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `ManyToManyField`s are populated. Create and save the model first, then use the [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) on the field.